# Compare C# list with SQL Column

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQL database with a `table` named `Item` and a `Column` named `Name`.

I also have List of a class which has a few `filename` in it. Code:

```
public class ClassNameHere
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
}
```

Let´s say in the database there are those Name´s:

`Name1` and `Name2`

And my list has the `filenames`:

`Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3` and `Name4`

Now I want to compare the list to the database and when the list has anything that the database does not have I want to select those and put it into another list. In this case `Name3` and `Name4` would be selected.

How do I write in in C# ?

I guess it has to be something like:

```
foreach(var vName in listFromClass)
var imAlist = Select Name From TableName Where vName.filename Not Name
```

Comment: I think since your edit the question has changed, quite a lot. Can you give specifics on what it is that you can't get working?

Comment: Something like `var notInDBNames = listFromClass.Where(n => !result.Any(d => d == n));`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with linq as follows:

```
var result = secondList.Where(secondListItem => !firstList.Any(firstListItem => firstListItem.ID == secondListItem.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with linq like this :

```
var notInDB = FilenamesList.Where(p => !listFromClass.Any(p2 => p2.filename ==p.filename));
```